# string trimming using linux "cut" respecting utf8 bondaries

Tags: linux, utf-8, cut

I am doing some text processing and I need to cut a string into short substrings. I used cut but it seems it will cut my string according to bytes. my texts are a mix of multibyte, utf8 encoded text and using cut will often result in the last few bytes being an invalid utf8 bytes, which will cause problem for my further processing.  so I was wondering if there is a proper way to do this?

P.S. I've try the -c parameter but it still cuts on bytes.

example, （machine locale is en_GB.UTF-8)

echo "是非常的危險" | cut -c -6

是非

echo "是非常的危險" | cut -c -7

是非

echo "是非常的危險" | cut -c -8

是非

echo "是非常的危險" | cut -c -9

是非常

Comment: Mmmm can you provide some examples? Bash has some [string operations](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22664)

Comment: Is your locale utf-8 aware?

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx the machine locale is en_GB.UTF-8, not sure what is "utf-8 aware"?

Comment: Basically anything `.UTF-8` is UTF-8 aware.  I would expect a modern `cut` to cope with this, but maybe yours is ancient?  Is this GNU Coreutils or a different `cut`?

Comment: I can reproduce his problem with 7 and 8 on recent coreutils (8.21). Sounds like a bug report waiting to happen.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx you are right, this is known... back to 2006! http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2006-07/msg00044.html

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for people who commented, apparently this is a known bug in linux coreutils:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2006-07/msg00044.html

dated back in 2006!

I have a "work-around" with the help of iconv -c which will ignore illegal bytes.

```
echo "是非常的危險" | cut -c -7 | iconv -c
```

which will yield valid sequence "是非" (no extra illegal bytes at the end)